# Select All Tags with Data Name - Get Value - Set Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have some HTML where I've dynamically printed a bunch of elements, some containing a specific `data` attribute. Because my templating language can't efficiently make use of regular expressions, I need to use JavaSript (or JQuery) to select the data values, build a string, then add that string as a class to that original element.

Example of HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-ses-cat="This Cool Thing (Yes)"></div>
```

Example of Desired HTML after JavaScript:

```
<div class="item this-cool-thing-yes" data-ses-cat="This Cool Thing (Yes)"></div>
```

I just need to add a class to **all** tags that contain `data-ses-cat` then get the value for that data attribute, run regex, then add that new string as a class.

I feel like it should be fairly simple, but I haven't touched a lot of JQuery in a while.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove every character that is not alphanumeric or a space, then lowercase it, then split on space, and join on dash.

```js
$('.item[data-ses-cat]').each(function(){
  var newClass = $(this).data('ses-cat')
      .replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '' )
      .toLowerCase()
      .split( ' ' )
      .join( '-' );
  
  this.classList.add( newClass );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-ses-cat="This Cool Thing (Yes)">Test</div>
```

And from your comments, here is a version that uses arrow functions.

```js
$('.item[data-ses-cat]').each((index, element)=>{
  var newClass = $(element).data('ses-cat')
      .replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '' )
      .toLowerCase()
      .split( ' ' )
      .join( '-' );
  
  element.classList.add( newClass );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-ses-cat="This Cool Thing (Yes)">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the job. I first tried with an es6 arrow and got undefined, apparently you can't use that in this context, so weird.

Comment: Arrow functions do not change what `this` is.  If you want a version that uses arrow functions I can add that.

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla JS version of the code would look something like this:

```
function processElement(element) {
    const clazz =
      element.dataset.sesCat.toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\(\)/g, '') // Remove brackets.
        .replace(/ /g, '-'); // Replace spaces with dashes.
    element.classList.add(clazz);
}

const sesCatElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ses-cat]');
sesCatElements.forEach(processElement);
```

Of course, you can tweak your RegExp exactly how you want it.

Here is some info on how [Dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access) works.

And this, is how you work with [CSS class names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods).

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the vanilla version!

Comment: @Kenny Of course! I hope your processing engine is not IE6, and supports all these features :)